# Two player game about maximizing earnings subject to an interesting condition

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, game-theory, average

Me and my friend had a bet. We each pick an integer between $1$ and $100$ inclusive and reveal it at the same time. Whoever picks the higher number has his number halved. Then the person whose number is lower (after this operation) has to pay the other person an amount equal to the difference.

For example, if my friend picks $80$ and I pick $48$ then he is forced to pay me $\$8$.

I have no idea what my friend will pick. What is the optimal number I should play to maximize my earnings?

Comment: What happens if the numbers are the same?

Comment: And you cannot pick an optimal number, at the very best you can hope that there exists an optimal strategy. However, if there exists such an optimal strategy for you, independent of your friends strategy, the same strategy would be optimal for you friend, which would result in a break-even at the long run.

Comment: If your friend always picks 1, you will soon learn what is the optimal number.

Comment: Assuming my friend is extremely intelligent, he will never pick the number 1 since it cannot guarantee a win. Therefore we can assume the numbers are between 2 and 100 instead. If the numbers are the same, nothing happens.

Comment: The game is equivalent to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485281/very-fascinating-probability-game-about-maximising-greed where the score is relative, not absolute.

Answer (score 1):

Playing $1$ is a dominated strategy. So, suppose your friend is playing $y\in \{2,\dots,100\}$, then your best response is to choose $x$ in the following way.

- If you choose $x=y$, the your payoff is $0$.
- If you choose $x>y$, the your payoff is $\frac{x}{2}-y$. So if you are going to choose $x>y$ you should choose $x=100$, which gives you a payoff of $\frac{100}{2}-y$.
- If you choose $x<y$, the your payoff is $x-\frac{y}{2}$. So if you are going to choose $x<y$ you should choose $x=y-1$, which gives you a payoff of $\frac{y}{2}-1$.

You will be indifferent between the last two choices if $$\frac{100}{2}-y=\frac{y}{2}-1 \Rightarrow y=34 $$

Hence, your best response function can be summarized as

$$ x= \begin{cases} y-1 &\text{, if }y>34 \\[1.5ex] \{33,100\} &\text{, if }y=34 \\[1.5ex] 100 &\text{, if }y<34 \end{cases}$$

Your friend's best response is symmetric. Since the two best response functions do not cross, there is no (pure-strategy) Nash equilibrium to this game.

Comment: $(100,100)$ can't be a Nash equilibrium since a player has incentive to deviate to $99$.

Comment: True, I will fix it.

Comment: @A.S. Do you agree now?

Comment: Yes. See a link above to a closely related question.